# Confusion about void main() in C

Tags: c, program-entry-point, void

In `int main()`, `return` value should indicate how the program exited. Generally, We represented by a `0` return value for normal termination and `1` for abnormal termination.

Then, I'm just curious to know, If `void main()` function not return any return value, then **How to operating System know that program normal terminate or not in C?**

Comment: `void` is not on the list of permitted return types for `main`. So just don't...

Comment: use `exit(1)` for instance.

Comment: Unless your implementation *specifically* documents `void main()` as a legal signature, the behavior is undefined - *any* result is possible (including a runtime error), and any result is allowed.  It depends on how the program is invoked, and what the OS expects to see in a specific location.

Answer (score 1):

`void main()` is not allowed by C standard. `main` should either return `int` or some implementation defined data type.

Comment: It's not *deprecated*; it was never a standard signature to begin with.  `main` was always intended to return `int`.

Comment: @JohnBode; Yeah. But it was in K&R and I may recalled it from there.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately there are too many references, even reputable ones, that used `void main()`.  27 years since the first ISO standard, and we're *still* fighting this battle.